# svn to git conversion (how to check the repository quality)

Tags: git

Currently I'm planning to help with a fairly large git conversion for an open-source project.
The repository is quite large so trial & error is slow (over 60,000 commits).

There are many questions relating to *how* a git conversion should be done but almost no details on how to check if the conversion is valid.

Of course there are basics like setting the revisions in both repos and comparing the contents of the repositories, but history, commit messages... moving files, tracking changes between branches etc - become more involved.

So my questions are:

- Which areas should be checked in a newly converted git repository to see that the conversion is correct and succeeded?
- What are the the gotcha's/pitfalls to watch out for?
- Can anyone suggest strategies for evaluating a converted svn project to be sure nothing went wrong during conversion?

---

**note**: currently we're using reposurgeon however that should have no baring on the answer, though it does mean we have to do a once-off conversion and *get-it-right*.

Comment: Maybe better to make the transition more gradual, i.e. keep Subvresion repository online (at least readonly) for some prolonged time? If there will be no error messages during conversion + after a year nobody will complain about any missing info, then consider the git repository stable; and in case of missing thing just fetch it from SVN.

Comment: @Vi, yep, we would be fools to throw away svn repo, I have a local copy (used for testing) and we keep backups of it. Even if we have SVN available and its possible (in principle) to go back and use it. - Once we have a months development - discovering some error is going to be very tricky to go back and rectify (I'm guessing it could be anyway, tools to rewrite history exist but are not trivial to use) - so likely we would just live with it which I like to try avoid.

Comment: In Git, if somebody has rewritten the history and published it (using `push --force`), you still can access the original history if you remembered original history's last commit SHA-1 value (and it's not garbage-collected yet). You can also set up the rule to prevent overwriting history during pushing using denyDelete and denyNonFastForward.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the git-svn plugin you can just clone your SVN repository with a local git client which effectively creates a Git repo complete with intact history.  Not only is this super easy and super quick but you can trust that you are properly synchronized with the existing svn repo and even pull changes that may have happened after the initial clone.

As for things to look out for, git does not track empty folders.  Another gotcha is dealing with binary files that you hopefully aren't storing in your existing repo. You dont want to store large binaries in a git repo typically. There are a few git specific solutions you can google but it might be tricky if you are pulling them by cloning the svn repo.

Comment: We tried https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git (which uses git-svn IIRC) and it was taking over a week to convert, multiple people tried on different systems (fast xeon servers, in-memory RAM conversions, fast SSD's - was still slow). I didnt want to get into conversion topic its self but this is why we went with reposurgeon which takes ~25min.

Comment: Yes, we have binary files in the repo too, many GB in fact, however we're not going to track them in git, reposurgeon can ignore them and we can manage them externally.

Comment: multiple gigabytes of binary blobs in git will make your daily life miserable. you would definitely want to exclude that from git if somehow possible.

Comment: @mnagel yes - we are ignoring them - but this is really unrelated to checking if a conversion is correct/good or not.

Comment: You could always write a bash script to iterate over all the files in each repo and diff the files. Seems unnecessary though.  I'm not sure you want to maintain 60k commits in a single git repo it may make a lot of its search/history functionality too slow to easily use. At the very minimum you won't want to distribute it much due to size which kind of defeats the point. I am no Git guru though and this looks like a task that should easily involve a few.  Personally, I would have just cut a new repo and started fresh with svn as an archive(I know you probably cant, sorry).

Comment: @Deadron, doing a clean start and loosing history is really a no-go, we have enough references to revisions in the code and I do go back and look at history to find out about whats going on, To have to step back to SVN for this would really be a loss IMHO. 60k commits includes branches, some we will not migrate, so final git repo will be smaller.

Comment: 60K isn't a fifth the size of the linux repo.  60k commits will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, just some things we have been doing to check the git conversion is ok.

Find all commits with 3+ parents, its quite unlikely these are valid, though there may be exceptions where it is.

```
git log --all --min-parents=3
```

Find all commits with duplicate parents. note that running git filter-branch can clean these up after, but that can sometimes be a really slow process.

```
git log --all --min-parents=2 --format="format:%H: %P" | egrep ':[^:]* ([0-9a-f]+) [^:]*\1'
```

Find all commits that are not merges and don't change any files (possibly svn props change):

```
git log --all --max-parents=1 --format="format:%H" --shortstat | pcregrep -v -M "^[a-z0-9]+\n "
```

*Thanks to Julien Rivaud for the regex commands!*